# typescript - function param type second rely on first one

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm a typescript newbie.

### Description

I have a typescript react application, and now I've had a problem that I need to dynamic watch the values comes out of the `watch()` from `react-hook-from` based on the different param that passed into my customized hook.

#### which means from cosumer side

when first param is `'k'`, typescript should be automatcally give suggestion and the type should be `interface kq`.

when first one is `'c'`, typescript should be automatcally give suggestion and the type should be `interface cq`.

I tried the below solution `type pqp<T> = T extends k ? kq : T extends c ? cq : never;`, but it seems union `'kq'` and `'cq'`, no matter what is the first param, it always suggest `'s'` and `'ce'`, which exists both in `'kq'` and `'cq'`.

I've been also trying a lot of solution on the internet, but it seems not working...post here ask for help.

### Hook Code Block

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

type k = 'k';
type c = 'c';

type p = k | c;

interface kq {
  s: string;
  t: string;
  ce: string;
}

interface cq {
  s: string;
  c: string;
  ce: string;
}

type pqp<T> = T extends k ? kq : T extends c ? cq : never;

const useMyHook = <T extends p>(product: T, qp?: pqp<T>) => {
  const generatedQP = useMemo(() => {
    if (product === 'c') {
      return ({
        will_return_s: qp?.s || '',
        will_return_ce: qp?.ce || 'default',
        will_return_c: qp?.c || '' // ERROR! property c does not exist on kq or cq. property c doesn not exist on kq
      }); 
    } else {
      return ({
        will_return_s: qp?.s || '',
        will_return_ce: qp?.ce || 'default',
        will_return_c: qp?.t || '' // ERROR! property t does not exist on kq or cq. property t doesn not exist on cq
      }); 
    }
  }, [product]);

  const methods = useForm({
    criterialMode: 'all',
    defaultValues: generatedQP
  })

  return methods;
}
```

### Consumer Code Block

```
function component() {
  const p: p = 'c';
  const { watch } = useMyHook(p)

  const {/** these will change and report error based on what p is */} = watch();
  // I also noticed that the type is always 'kq' for watch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `enum` to store the values.

```js
enum Types {
  k = 'k',
  c = 'c',
}

interface kq {}

interface cq {}

type pqp<T> = T extends Types.k ? kq : T extends Types.c ? cq : never;

const useMyHook = <T extends `${Types}`>(product: T, qp?: pqp<T>) => {
  return {
    watch: () => qp,
  };
};

function component() {
  const p = Types.k;

  const { watch } = useMyHook(p);
  console.log(watch);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to narrow type of `qp` when you use it:

```
// if product is 'c' than qp is cq, otherwise it's kp
const isCq = (product: c | k, qp?: kq | cq): qp is cq => product === "c";

// define the arguments as unions
const useMyHook = (product: c | k, qp?: kq | cq) => {
  const generatedQP = useMemo(() => {
    if (isCq(product, qp)) { // use the guard to narrow the type of `qp`
      return {
        will_return_s: qp?.s || "",
        will_return_ce: qp?.ce || "default",
        will_return_c: qp?.c || "",
      };
    } else {
      return {
        will_return_s: qp?.s || "",
        will_return_ce: qp?.ce || "default",
        will_return_c: qp?.t || "",
      };
    }
  }, [product, qp]);

  const methods = useForm({
    criteriaMode: "all",
    defaultValues: generatedQP,
  });

  return methods;
};
```